# Garbage after string

Tags: c

I've written code to copy a string into another string but with a space between each character. When I run the code there is "garbage" after the string. However, if the for loop at the end is uncommented, there is no garbage after. Anyone know why this is happening?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 20
main ()
{
    char name[MAX_SIZE+ 1]; 
    char cpy[(MAX_SIZE * 2) + 1];

    gets(name);

    int i = 0;

    while (name[i] != '\0' && i < MAX_SIZE)
    {
        cpy[(i * 2)] = name[i];
        cpy[(i * 2) + 1] = ' ';
        i++;
    }

    cpy[strlen(cpy)] = '\0';    

    printf("%s\n", cpy);

    //for (i = 0; i < strlen(cpy); ++i) {
    //    printf("%c", cpy[i]);
    //}

}
```

Comment: side note use `fgets()` not `gets()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line

```
cpy[strlen(cpy)] = '\0';
```

won't work since `cpy` isn't null terminated so `strlen` will read beyond the end of `name` until it either crashes or finds a zero byte of memory.  You can fix this by changing that line to

```
cpy[i*2] = '\0';
```

If uncommenting the for loop at the end of your function appears to fix things, I can only guess that `i` gets reset to 0 before your `printf` call, meaning that `printf` finds a null terminator on the stack immediately after `cpy`.  If this is what's happening, its very much undefined behaviour so cannot be relied upon.

Comment: Assuming a space at the end of the string is desired, otherwise it should be `cpy[i*2-1] = '\0';`

Answer (score 2):

```
 while (name[i] != '\0' && i < MAX_SIZE)
    {
        cpy[(i * 2)] = name[i];
        cpy[(i * 2) + 1] = ' ';
        i++;
    }
 cpy[(i * 2)] = 0x0;
```

You have to null terminate the string.

Answer (score 1):

Because you know that you are working with a string, it's a good thing if you initialize your "cpy" array with null character :

```
 char cpy[(MAX_SIZE * 2) + 1]  = "\0";
```

Otherwise, I agreed with simonc answer.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness:

```
char* pcpy = cpy;
for (char const* p = fgets(name,sizeof(name)/sizeof(*name),stdin); p && *p; ++p) {
  *pcpy++ = *p;
  *pcpy++ = ' ';
}
*pcpy = 0;
```

You should use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), not [`gets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets) in order to prevent your stack to be corrupted by data overruns. Second, You must manually terminate the string stored in the `cpy` array, since [`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) simply counts the number of characters until the very first zero. Hence, if you haven't already terminated `cpy` the result of `strlen(cpy)` will be undefined and most likely crash your program.